# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): dataItem already in tree Abort (core dumped)

Tags: c++, tree

I'm getting the error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::invalid_argument'what():  dataItem already in tree Abort (core
>   dumped)

i've tried everything and i can't think of anything to possibly fix this i'm assuming im storing the tree when its already stored but i have no idea, any help would be appreciated
Below is my Code - i also use bintree and binNode :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bintree.h"
#include "binnode.h"
using namespace std;

class mazePoint    
{
  private:
  int x;
  char pointType;

  public:

   void setPointMaze(char ch, int i)
   {
       pointType = ch;
       x = i;
   }

   bool operator == (const mazePoint &other) const
   {
      return(this->x == other.x);
   }
   bool operator < (const mazePoint &other) const
   {
      return(this->x < other.x);
   }
};

class mazeRow
{
   private:
   bintree<mazePoint> points;
   int y;

   public:

   void setMazeRow(int rowNumber)
   {
      y = rowNumber;
   }

   bool operator==(const mazeRow &other) const
   { 
      return(this->y < other.y);
   }

   bool operator<(const mazeRow &other) const
   {
      return(this->y < other.y);
   }

   void storePointMaze(char ch, int i)
   {
      mazePoint point;
      point.setPointMaze(ch,i);
      points.insert(point);
   }

   void incrementeRow()
   {
     y++;
   }
};

void loadMaze(bintree<mazeRow> &maze, const char *filein, int argc);
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   unsigned int  start = 0;
   unsigned int  finish = 0;
   bintree<mazeRow> maze;
   string filein;
   loadMaze(maze, argv[1], argc); 
   return 0;
}

void loadMaze(bintree<mazeRow> &maze, const char *filein, int argc)
{

   if ( argc < 2) {
      cout << "Must supply 1 argument to this program";
      exit(0);
   } 
    mazeRow row;
   ifstream infile(filein);      

   char temp;
   unsigned int i = 0;

   if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()) {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            infile.get(temp);
            i++;
      row.storePointMaze(temp, i);
      if(temp == '\n') ./
      {         
         maze.insert(row);
         row.incrementeRow();
      }
         }

   }
   else {
      cout << "Failed to open file..";      
   }
   infile.close();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: please use a debugger in order to identify the line (or at least the function) causing the error

Comment: A guess would be that `bintree` (whatever _that_ is) is throwing an exception because some value you're trying to store is already contained in it.  We don't know what a `bintree` is though, so it's hard to really say.  Suggest wrapping a `try`/`catch` around `points.insert(point)` and log the conflicting values.  That should give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there is an exception being thrown that is not caught in your code. This is most probably being thrown in `binTree` implementation, when you try to insert an element whose key is already in?

You can use a debugger to break at the point where the exception is thrown (in gdb `catch throw` would be the command) and you can then inspect why you ended up in this situation.